# Override sorting in WPF DataGrid / ListCollectionView

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, listcollectionview

I've overridden a ListCollectionView to lazy load only those items which are needed for display.

I'm using this ListCollectionView in a DataGrid to show and edit items.

This works nicely, just like it should.

My problem: I want the user to be able to sort the DataGrid by clicking on the header column. Since I lazy load the items only when I need them, the ListCollectionView does a bad job on sorting those items which has not been loaded yet.

One way to solve this would be to load all items, but I don't want to do that since this might be way too many items to load in a respectable time.

Instead I would like to get the notification and tell my (remote) data source to hand me the items pre-sorted instead.

Is there an easy way to intercept the sorting in either the DataGrid or (better) the ListCollectionView and do it myself, somehow?

Comment: .. as I said in other topic created by you : I think, you need to explore [ListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview_properties.aspx) first, as it is able fit into most scenarios programmers usually want to implement in their application. Most likely, you would not need to derive this class to do lazy loading. You can use Filter instead, and there are other approach to do Lazy load, without deriving the class.

Comment: Load 400000 items from a cloud service to do filtering on the client is not really a solution I could possibly work with :)

Comment: But you are probably right and I need more information about ListCollectionView - I'm open for any information or decent source explaining it, so far I had no luck, thats why I ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you need for a data virtualization, there is a special library for this on [codeplex](http://datavirtualization.codeplex.com).
All that you have to do is to implement the following method:

```
public IList<T> LoadRange(int startIndex, int count, 
                SortDescriptionCollection sortDescriptions, out int overallCount)
```

Inside this method you can call a WCF-service and return a sorted and truncated list.
This library isn't easy to understand, but it works.

Comment: I'd rather just have information how I get a notification if sorting order has changed.

Comment: It is not a question that can be explained in few sentences. In general, a sequence consist of the following steps: construct CollectionView with callback-function as a parameter -> handle ListViewHeader click event -> in a handler get CollectionView and call Refresh method -> in a refresh method call the callback function and do something with an inner list.